# How can I can bodyToMono twice?

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a validator method that takes a string and throws an error if the incoming request is not valid - I can't refactor this.  I would like to call `bodyToMono(String.class)` to run the validation and then again `bodyToMono(MyRequestBody.class)` to continue execution in my handler class.

Is this possible?

I'm thinking something like:

```java
serverRequest.bodyToMono(String.class)
  .doOnNext(validator::validateRequestString)
  .bodyToMono(MyRequestBody.class)
  .map(request -> proceed())
```

If not possible, then I have to manually unmarshall the string to `MyRequestBody` object.

Comment: that is not possible. Why not deserialize it into your object, then wrap the validation function, and create a toString function that converts the object to a string representation.

Comment: Why not validate the MyRequestBody?

Comment: did you found solution for this. ??